# python not found while NPM install

Tags: python, angularjs, node.js, npm-install

while am try to check node modules for the new project in angular 1.5 it throws the below error. kindly anyone helps me to resolve

node version:8
npm version 5.2.0
python version: 3.6.1
already Python is running on my machine with the version of 3.6.1 environment variables also configured for the python. please find the below screen shot for the npm error and environment variables

1.

[npm install command python error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbuEj.jpg)

2. [environment variables set reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ektpf.jpg)

Comment: define PYTHON variable to the path where executable is present. are you sure python.exe is present at *C:\\python36-32\* ?

Comment: I set an environment variable like this:                                                                         C:\Python36-32\python.exe

Comment: I was sceptical because PYTHON variable is not present in screenshot.

Comment: i defined like python2

Comment: @Muthunsankar, I am not sure if python2 will work. for now, just create a new environment variable PYTHON and assign it the path where Python executable exists